# Boolean value in properties file

Tags: java, properties

As we know that in properties file every *value* is treated as String.
For example I've a property in my file:

```
XYZ=false
```

I want to use the String **false** above as a boolean value in a condition. The problem is that I **can not** modify the java source executing this condition *XYZ*:

```
if (XYZ) {
  //do something
}
```

Currently this condition always returns the String *true* instead of a boolean with the value *false*.

**Can I do something in properties file to make it a boolean?**

Comment: Can you show us what you are doing because what you suggest wouldn't even compile?  Have you tried using `Boolean.parseBoolean` or similar?

Comment: @LyubenTodorov You might like to use `equalsCaseIgnore` which is what Boolean uses. ;)

Comment: XYZ must be an expression which evaluates to *true* or *false*. How does the expression look like?

if (Boolean.FALSE.equals(yourProperty))?
if (false == yourProperty)?

Comment: Please understand the question first and then answer

Comment: I think you have the best chance when you extend the java class. Overwrite the method you are talking about.

Answer (score 2):

After get the value from properties file, you can use this: if (Boolean.valueOf(XYZ)) {...}

Comment: Please read the question once again. I can't edit the java file

Comment: I don't understand what you mean? You can't edit the file but you can read it and after that you convert it into boolean in java.

Comment: The java file is inside a jar file .. and I dont want to make the jar file again

Comment: Recreate the JAR is your best option, as the Java code would be valid with what you want to do (i.e. comparing to "true").